# Prevent read from special character input

Tags: linux, bash

How can I prevent or check for invalid input from `read`?

As you can see I'm asking user for name of a feature directory but it still reads characters that can't be put in directory name.

```
read -p 'Enter directory name: ' create_dir
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Linux, The only characters that cannot be part of a directory name are `/` and the null byte `\0`. The null byte cannot be stored inside a bash variable. So all you have to check for is the `/` and the empty name.

The sane way to handle invalid input would be

```
while
  read -rp 'Enter directory name: ' create_dir &&
  [[ -z "$create_dir" || "$create_dir" == */* ]]
do
  echo "Empty names or names containing '/' are forbidden."
done
declare -p create_dir
```

However, it seems you want to "disable" the <kbd>/</kbd> key and also disable <kbd>enter</kbd> unless the user wrote something valid. With some tricks, this can be done too. But some users may get freaked out by this because you never explained anything to them.

```
printf 'Enter directory name: '
create_dir=
while 
  read -rsN1 char &&
  [[ -z "$create_dir" || "$char" != $'\n' ]]
do
  [[ "$char" = / || "$char" = $'\n' ]] && continue
  create_dir+=$char     
  printf %s "%char"
done
echo
declare -p create_dir
```

As I said, I wouldn't recommend this. With above approach the user also loses the ability to correct their input using <kbd>backspace</kbd>.

Comment: Wow! Thanks! It's all nice written and it's what I needed!

Comment: @spyx33, you might also want to restrict directory names *beginning* with `/` -- or at least check for the ability to create a directory in the user's chosen  dir.